# .NET Core cshtml don't know how to pass single string to Controller

Tags: razor, .net-core

I have an issue with a personal project i am doing. I am trying to get the text from an input text field and pass it to a new controller which will display all search results associated with the text.

The issue is, i am rather confused and don't know how to structure the Html for the form.

```
        <div class="searchBox">
            <form>
                <input id="searchCriteria" name="id" type="text" class="form-control" />
                <button onclick="@Url.Action("Index", "SearchResults", "new { id = id}")" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

If anyone could help, that'd be great.

Comment: Is your problem getting the input text to bind to your model in the controller?  if so can you post the model?  I'm unsure if that is the issue or displaying the search results?  Can you update your question to clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms

Check your form tag.  You want to post the entire form to the controller.  Then you will be able to have a parameter named searchCriteria to consume that form value.

Comment: Yep this works, thanks. It can be quite difficult to sort through all the documentation sometimes.